# Android calculate length or distance between two points in Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, distance, pixel

[image]
I have an image drawn using canvas. And I mark two points and a line between them on the canvas. I need to calculate the length of the line or the distance between the two points.
I use the formula Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)) to calculate distance between two points and get a value like 250.82 or so. The resultant values is in pixels. How can I convert them to metric values or in the units of mm and cm ? I find many pixel to cm calculators online but they give me wrong answer which doesnt match with the real distance between two points. Can someone help me pls ?

Comment: Are you trying to develop map application or similar kind of application ?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Comment: @TugrulAsik Its not similar to a map application to calculate distance between two locations. Its just about calculating distance between two points on canvas

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
public static float getRealCm(int pixels, DisplayMetrics displayMetrics)
    {
        float dpi = (float) displayMetrics.densityDpi;

        float inches = pixels / dpi;

        return inches * 2.54f; //inches to cm
    }
```

`DisplayMetrics` can be obtained from `Resources`. You can write in your activity: `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()`

Comment: Are you sure about this calculation? My pixel values are in the datatype double. My device has high density screen, so the value would be 240. To convert 250.82 pixels into cm, this calculation gives 2.65 cm. But I think the real length is about 9 cm.

Comment: For my device it works fine. I do not think 250 px on device with 240 dpi should result in 9 cm. 240 px is one inch so it is one inch and than another 10 px which is only small part of inch so result is approx 1.04 inches which is 2.65 cm. 9 cm on 240 dpi device should lead to (9 / 2.54) * 240 pixels which is a bit more than 850 px. So yes, I am sure about my calculation. Check if the coordinates you use are related to same start.

Comment: I am using scaling gestures on the canvas image to zoom and drag. Will that affect this calculation to get accurate length?

Comment: Maybe, I do not know. Pixels should be pixels no matter on zooming. But I can imagine when you zoom the picture and then take coordinates from not zoomed picture the result can be 250 px but on the screen the size of image is completely different at that time. So I would guess it has something to do with zooming. Try my method above on something not zoomed and you will see it is correct.

Comment: See the image attached to my question at the top. The distance between two points is drawn using a red line and according to your calculation, I m getting 1.35 cm whereas the real physical distance is about 6 cm.

Comment: From which device is the screen captured? You mean real physical distance on the hand? The calculation I am talking about is physical size on screen display and if the screen width is 720 px, which i see on screen image, with 240 dpi, it gives me 7.62 cm on screen width and red line takes approximately one fifth or sixth of screen width so the measured size 1.36 cm match. Of course it does not match real size of hand. Real hand size cannot be calculated easily just with pixels.

Comment: oops...I am talking about real hand size. If it cannot be just easily calculated with pixels, may I know how could it be calculated?

Comment: Well, I think this is very complicated topic to another question. You will need some extra information than just pixel count to calibrate your measuring. In fact it has its own discipline called Photogrammetry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry